# kotlin two rows in layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This question is derived because of this exercise to build quadrants [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems#3).

In the excersize we are asked to make a layout that has four quadrants and, so I made a row, added two col in the row, and made them fill up the space and added in the text.

Now I am playing around this a bit more and thought what if I added a 2nd row after the first row? would that give me two rows? So I tried that but it didn't change anything in the preview.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme.colorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import org.nynacs.steambadger.R

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeBasicsTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    ComposeScreen2()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposeScreen2() {
    Row(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(1f)
    ) {
        Column(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.text_comp),
                description = stringResource(R.string.text_comp_explained),
                _color = 0xFFEADDFF,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.image_comp),
                description = stringResource(R.string.image_comp_explained),
                _color = 0xFFD0BCFF,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }

        Column(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.row_comp),
                description = stringResource(R.string.row_comp_explained),
                _color = 0xFFB69DF8,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.col_comp),
                description = stringResource(R.string.col_comp_explained),
                _color = 0xFFF6EDFF,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
    }

    // add a new row here but the preview doesn't show another row?
    Row(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(1f)
    ) {
        Column(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.text_comp),
                description = stringResource(R.string.text_comp_explained),
                _color = 0xFFEADDFF,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.image_comp),
                description = stringResource(R.string.image_comp_explained),
                _color = 0xFFD0BCFF,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
        Column(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.row_comp),
                description = stringResource(R.string.row_comp_explained),
                _color = 0xFFB69DF8,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.col_comp),
                description = stringResource(R.string.col_comp_explained),
                _color = 0xFFF6EDFF,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposableInfoCard(title: String, description: String, _color: Long, modifier: Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(_color))
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    )
    {
        Text(
            text = title,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
        )
        Text(
            text = description,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    ComposeBasicsTheme {
        ComposeScreen2()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues. The first one being that adding the second `Row` displays that row on top of the first row. The reason for that is that you didn't provide a layout that determines how those two rows should be positioned in relation to each other. Remember: A `Row` is not called so because it is a row in a table, so that two successive rows would be layed out vertically. It is called a *row* because it distributes its children horizontally in a row. Now, what you need is another layout component that lays out the two rows vertically. You already know and use that layout component: It is a `Column`. Just wrap your two `Row`s in an additional `Column` and you are set.

Except that there is the second issue: You define the size of both rows with the modifier `fillMaxSize(1f)`. That means they take all the available space. (`1f` meaning 100%). But when the first row already takes the entire space, there is no room left for the second row: Although it will take up the entire available space (100%), there is none available after the first row has already taken it all. 100% of nothing is still nothing, so the second row is dropped. Fix this by reducing the rows' size, for example by setting it to `0.5f`.